# Changing jaxws-maven-plugin lifecycle

Tags: maven, jax-ws

We would like to create a project which use *jaxws-maven-plugin* *wsimport* to generate Java classes from WSDL. However we would like to switch the wsimport lifecycle from default *generate-sources* to *custom* lifecycle. How can we do that?

For example, we would like to be able to call *wsimport* plugin manually by calling the *custom* phase like *wsimport-generate-sources*.

Comment: What do you mean by *custom* lifecycle?

Comment: Add clarification in the question to answer @khmarbaise's question

Answer (score 0):

You simply define the lifecycle phase in which you want the plugin to execute in the `executions` section of the plugin configuration in your pom. This is done via the `<phase>` tag.

So for example to have jaxws-maven-plugin execute in the `test` phase you would simply do the following:

```
<project>
  ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>                    
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                         <id>myCustomExecution</id>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>wsimport</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <phase>test</phase>
                         <configuration>
                             ...                 
                         </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  ...
</project>
```

More details can be seen here:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag